# Generic Repository and multiple PK types

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I am trying to Implement a Generic Repository with Linq To SQL.  My problem lies in that some of my underlying tables have `int` ID's and some `Guid` ID's.  How would I account for that?

```
public T GetById(int id)
{
    return this._context.GetTable<T>().Single(x => x.ID.Equals(id));
}
```

Comment: Use a generic type for the type of the key

Comment: Are you sure you need a generic repo? All your repos have the exact same methods? You're using a repository simply to hide the 'ugly' linq2sql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add another generic parameter to the repository interface.

```
public interface IRepo<TType, PKType>
{
    TType GetById(PKType id);
}
```

Then implement it.

```
public class CustomerRepo : IRepo<Customer, Guid>
{
    public Customer GetById(Guid id)
    {
        // code to get from repo
    }
}
```

Comment: -1. THis will not work as there is nothing that even tells  the compiler the field. TTYpe has no limitation to a field named Id so this does not compile.

Comment: It does compile, just tested it.

Comment: Just be sure to use '(x => x.ID.Equals(id))' and not '(x => x.ID == id)'

Answer (score -3):

Well, first - A GetById makes no sense to start, ever heard of LINQ? Let the USER decide. Get if anything.

Second, even IF you insist on that, there is still generics.

GetById (T id)

would go that far, you can have more than one Type on a generic, but you assume then "id" as name, which requires an interface.

As fact, you have more grave problems, as

> GetTable().Single(x => x.ID.Equals(id));

is likely blowing in the compiler in this case, there is no limitation that requires T to have an id field. As such, you an not use it in a generic method.

THAT SAID - as I said in the beginning, by stripping the user from the power of a signficant part of the language (linq) you are basically creating yet another antipattern implementation of a generic bad repository.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm curious, however, as to why you feel the way you do.  I took this from a Pluralsight Course(http://pluralsight.com/training), which I thought to be well respected.  Perhaps I did not provide enough context in my question?

Comment: No, you did provide enough context. The problem is maintenance and usability - what if you need reports? What if you need 100 id's ? Make 100 calls - slow. Or make hundreds of access methods? Gratulations - mainteannce nightmare. LINQ is .NET core by now, the compiler knows it, nothing bad in exposing an IQUeryable up to whoever has to get the objects.

Comment: Actually it can be bad to expose IQueryable. This means that every db provider should implement that. If you are SURE you won't change from using linq2sql then it's not a problem.

Comment: @MikeSW Ridiculous. What about saying "We expect any db Provider to be written for .NET and not an outdated Version and LINQ is part of the core language spec and I am unwilling to give up a TON of Advantages so some dude can push in his crappy outdated Driver? Nothing against "replacability" but you seem to really love "old and oudated just in case we really may Need it once".

Comment: Try doing IQueryable with a micro orm. And I'm using a lot Linq but with objects. For db my app knows about repositories. No IQueryable because a repository interface is more easier to understand in the business context.

Comment: @MikeSW Done so. I use BlToolkit for that. Nice MicroORM and works like a charm. Performance ROCKS. Full and nice Linq implementation.

Comment: Not all of them have it though. Anyway the point of using a repository in the first place is to not depend on some specific data access solution

Comment: Linq2Sql is something specific. I'm using LINQ just NOT the db related part. IQueryable has no place when dealing with a repository as it's not a domain/business concept. I'm choosing to use a tool when it's appropriate not because it's cool, it's part of the core and it's not outdated.

Comment: You're just trolling right now implying that I write crappy code just because I don't agree with you. LINQ and IQUeryable can't have domain concepts as tehy are language constructs and the domain isn't C# itself. You can sue LINQ and IQUeryable within a Domain, but it has nothing to do with the domain itself. Furthermore the domain doesn't care about IQueryable because it's an implementation detail, one mostly used when dealing with "out of process" data. For "in process" an IEnumerable is as good. Why does the Domain need to know about the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable?

Comment: You can 'fake' an IQueryable from an IEnumerable but you're losing the benefits. Besides, at most, the Domain really wants a list of something filtered according to a criteria. It doesn't ask the repository for a builder for the criteria, it specifies a crtieria and tells the repository to return that list. Really, it's all about SRP and decoupled code. With or without "outdated" features. Btw, I'm not using very often the dynamic keyword. I still use strongly typing (with 'var') the old and outdated way.

Comment: @MikeSW Why you even bring up the dynamic keyeword? Guess what - I pass through anonymous types, I allow IQueryable against businsso objects, I have NOT ONCE used the dynamic keyword.

Comment: We make it a policy not to leak IQuerable into the service layers.  #1  Junior level developers have unchecked access to the dbs.  Imagine a .contains query on a non indexed field on a  multiple million record table.  How about when you decide to replace your database with call to an enterprise WCF/ServiceBus service?  IQueryable looks pretty dumb in this scenario.

Comment: @Darthg8r And you do not even know how to limit the queries in the exposed IQueryable to a max number? Whow. Anyhow, I make ure junior level code is checked with code reviews. What if they HAVE to do that for an app? Dead end.